# Do I really need to build a class diagram AND a component diagram?

Tags: modeling, diagrams, class-diagram, component

I'm modeling a system while improving my knowledge of software engineering. I am building a class diagram and a component diagram, but notice that when I tweak one, I have to alter the other. Also, I feel like I can represent the classes in a component diagram. How do you do this? Do you make them both or only one? If one, which is the best or when to use one or the other?

Thank you!

Comment: Design using code then generate the two diagrams from that code with some UML-generating tool. That way, they are both an accurate representation of your solution and you don't have to waste time manually creating them. Job done. Onto the next project...

Comment: And if you want to really improve your knowledge of software engineering, skip straight to the end and just learn why [UML is a stinking pile of horse manure](https://blog.codinghorror.com/unwanted-modeling-language/) and never touch it again. It'll save you a lot of wasted effort trying to learn to use the thing. You can then start learning useful SE principles like test first, CI/CD, clean coding etc.

Comment: You don't *need* any diagrams at all.

Comment: @DavidArno, perhaps my mindset is not the correct one, but I think of a diagram as a tool to guide my implementation (coding task). If I get to code without one, then I will end up not building one. I'm really on the path to learning SE principles and most sources include UML diagrams as a way to model a system. Now, I read the article you linked to and it makes sense. Maybe I'll try finishing this project without focussing much on UML diagrams and them take time later to learn better. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertHarvey, if I understand your point, yes, I can build a program without any. I'm doing Udacity's "Software Development Process" and they teach class diagram and then component diagram for the same system. My question was more like, if I **want** to model a system, like one including server side and web plus front end apps and ***want** to do it using UML diagrams, because I **want** to learn, can I have a good representation with just a class diagram? With just a component diagram? Is using both better or a redunduncy? I now get from the answer that they're different things.

Comment: Diagrams are primarily a tool to communicate ideas to other people, or to help organize your own thoughts; they are ephemeral, and as a system changes they will go out of date. You'll often throw them away. You may use them to document some of the more stable high-level structures; if you document implementation details, you have the same problem with any kind of external documentation, not just UML, so you have to find a balance there; also, writing self-documenting code helps (meaningful names, comments where appropriate, consistency, readability, simplicity, etc.)

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, thanks for your input. There is no one else I have to show the diagrams at the moment. I'm modeling in order to have a good base to start coding this system, but also to learn UML modeling. I've built other small programs successfully without diagrams before. This time I must make sure to start by following the best practices as much as I can, including self-documenting code. Again, thank you!

Comment: "*I think of a diagram as a tool to guide my implementation (coding task)*". That to my mind is where folk go wrong with software engineering, which leads them down the path of thinking they need the likes of UML. Coding is design. Your code is the only design document that you create that precisely describes your design. And that design then precisely tells the compiler how to build your app according to your design. People all too often, completely wrongly in my view, equate implementation with "build", not with "design".

Comment: Diagrams absolutely can help you shape that design and can help explain it after the code is created. But as @FilipMilovanović says, they should be ephemeral in the first case, and obviously they should be created after the code is written in the latter case.

Comment: I apologize for the problems with the question. It's my first one here and in a field where I'm new. I would edit it, but I don't like doing it when others are already answering. Might leave the answers out of context. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to build both? Maybe. It depends. I'd say that if there is a 1:1 mapping between classes in a UML Class Diagram and components in a UML Component Diagram, you probably don't need both diagrams.

The intention of both diagrams is different, though. Class diagrams specifically show classes (and modules or packages), along with their attributes, methods, and relationships. You can get into the details of interfaces and abstract classes and visibility (public, private, protected) of attributes and methods, aggregation and composition, and so on. Of course, the level of detail in a class diagram depends on the audience. Component diagrams are a higher level of abstraction. A component could be something more like a module, an API, a service, an application, a database. If you are building in an object-oriented language, I would suspect that a component would be a set of classes, perhaps a deployable unit.

If you find yourself changing a Component Diagram every time you make a change to a Class Diagram, your Component Diagram is probably at too low of a level of abstraction. I'd think harder about what a "component" is and if it makes sense to use the Component Diagram for your system.

Comment: "your Component Diagram is probably at too low of a level of abstraction". This might be the problem. Thank you very much!